# Awaited method call doesnt appear to complete

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have just started to learn asynchronous coding and have run into a problem.

So this is what I am trying to do.

1. I have a method which calls two awaited methods asynchronously. For testing purposes each method is calling a stored procedure which executes `WAITFOR DELAY 'xxx'`.
2. Within each method call another method needs to run alongside it to generate three loading dots appended to the text value passed in.
3. So when `await Task.Run(() => DisableReplication("Disable Replication"))` is running (calling the stored procedure for say 10 secs) it will display

   > Disabling Replication.
   > Disabling Replication..
   > Disabling Replication...

   until that stored procedure has finished, then it should say

   > Disabling Replication - Complete

   Then it should call `await Task.Run(() => ImportWeights("Importing Weights"))`, where for example the proc takes 20 secs to complete. So it will display

   > Importing Weights.
   > Importing Weights..
   > Importing Weights...

   Then once complete it will say

   > Import Weights - Complete.

Within each method there is a bool value being set from false to true once the method has finished. That value is used in the `ShowProgressText` method in the while loop. Once the value is set to true it should break out.

At present it is doing the 1st part fine with displaying 'Disabling Replication' but once that method is completed it starts switching between 'Disabling Replication' and 'Importing Weights'. I assumed the Disabling Replication method was finished so I am not sure why it continues to pick the text up. I think the issue is with the `ShowProgressText` method.

Does anyone known what I am doing wrong and perhaps if I could simplify this somehow?

Here is a .gif showing what it is doing and the code I am using is below.

[image]

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DirectMailSpendManagement
{
    public partial class FrmRapport : AestheticsFormBase
    {    
        #region Instantiations
        private readonly RapportDataAccess access = new RapportDataAccess();
        private readonly Panel panel = new Panel();
        #endregion
        
        #region Fields
        private bool IsCompleted;
        #endregion
        
        #region Constructors
        public FrmRapport()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        #endregion
        
        #region Private Methods
        private void BtnGetRapportFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _ = LoadRapport();
        }
        
        private async Task LoadRapport()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => DisableReplication("Disable Replication"));
            await Task.Run(() => ImportWeights("Importing Weights"));
        }
        
        private void DisableReplication(string txt)
        {
            IsCompleted = false;
            Task.Run(() => ShowProgressText(txt));
            access.DisableReplication();
        }
        
        private void ImportWeights(string txt)
        {
            IsCompleted = false;
            Task.Run(() => ShowProgressText(txt));
            access.ImportAndCalculateWeights(panel.PanelNumber, "", "", "");
        }
        
        private void ShowProgressText(string txt)
        {
            var count = 0;
            var logText = new StringBuilder();
        
            logText.Append(txt);
            var baseLen = logText.Length;
        
            while (!IsCompleted)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(300);
                if (count >= 3)
                {
                    logText.Remove(baseLen, count);
                    count = 0;
                }
        
                logText.Append(".");
                count++;
        
                BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { UpdateProgressText(logText.ToString()); }));
            }
        
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { UpdateProgressText(txt + " - Complete"); }));
        }
        
        private void UpdateProgressText(string txt)
        {
            lblProgress.Text = txt;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills yep, will do. New to this site so learning the rules 

Comment: @GSerg As I said in the question, I am new to asynchronous coding so I have misunderstood how async/await works. I will update the code and see if it works

Comment: @AlfieHillier I retract my previous statement. While it is true that you are not awaiting anything and it's a mess, you wanted to create a separate loop that keeps updating a label periodically while the rest of the code goes forward. It's better to do with a timer, not with a tangle of tasks. Also please use https://www.screentogif.com/ instead of filming your screen.

Comment: @GSerg 'a mess'. Thanks for the constructive criticism. As I have said and I will repeat, I am new to asynchronous coding so came here for some advice. And I am using await in the LoadRapport method, no? Also, not sure what the problem is with filming my screen. It allowed you to see what the issue was didnt it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is you have two separate tasks running that call ShowProgressText.  Task.Run() is not something you normally use unless you are interfacing with code that does not use the C# async/await pattern.  So perhaps LoadRapport could be like this:

```
    bool IsCompleted;
    string LogText;

    private async Task LoadRapport()
    {
        LogText = "Disable Replication";
        IsCompleted = false;

        _ = ShowStatus(); // start this task but don't wait for it to finish.

        // Start these long running methods on a separate non UI thread using Task.Run.
        await Task.Run(() => DisableReplication());

        LogText = "Importing Weights";

        await Task.Run(() => ImportWeights());

        IsCompleted = true; // tell ShowStatus to complete.
    }
```

and ShowStatus could be like this:

```
    async Task ShowStatus()
    {
        while (!IsCompleted) {
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                UpdateProgressText(this.LogText);
            })); ;
            await Task.Delay(200);
        }

        UpdateProgressText("Completed");
    }
```

I would also remember to disable the button that calls BtnGetRapportFile during this long running process so the user doesn't click it 10 times and get 10 separate threads running calling your SQL server...

Comment: Thank you. Looks like a better solution. I am struggling to get the text to append the three loading dots whilst each method is running.